# Getting photo timestamp using Drive API

Tags: api, google-drive-api, google-photos

As Google Photos API is not available yet, I am trying to fetch Photos information over Drive API.

I can access all interested information except one: `Photo Timestamp` - the value used by Google Photos to order photos in albums and the timeline.

In Google Photos web interface it is possible to set `Photo Timestamp` including a time zone. This information is not available over Drive API.

For example, you can change `Photo Timestamp` by editing Data & Time of the photo in Google Photos web interface, but this change will not be reflected in any of the fields that are exposed through Drive API for pictures.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google Photos version of 'timestamp' in Drive API. The only way you can access [gphoto:timestamp](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/reference#gphoto_timestamp) element is to use [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).

For example when I ran

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default
```

in my browser, it returned a feed of album entries. The timestamp element looks like this:

```
< gphoto:timestamp >1118992182000< /gphoto:timestamp >
```

You can read more of that in the guide. Hope this helps.

Comment: Kindly state why you downvoted my answer? I answered the question with regard to Drive Files as best I can.

Comment: What new information did you provide with the "answer"?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Pity that Google Drive does not expose all the information for the photos. It also means, that photos stored only in Drive do not have this information at all 